# Mobile Safari - Show console?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, cordova

To prevent the default scrolling of a page I'm adding an event listener for "touchstart" events on the body and calling `event.preventDefault()` This works fine but I now can't access the debug console as it requires a page drag? Has anyone else had this problem and come up with a work around?

Comment: perfect example of why disabling scrolling is a terrible idea unless you are doing anything other than developing an HTML-based game.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, interesting.  Perhaps you can limit the scope of the bind to a less-encompassing region of the page, let's say an 'inner div' on the page, but not an 'outer div'?  Then, perhaps you can leave yourself a small amount of margin between them for you to invoke the console?

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that a user may swipe this area and scroll the page? I think what I may need to do is identify the element the console output is in (if it is an element?) and move it down?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest adding a parameter to the url by which you can reactivate scrolling